How to open token based Php form in same session
A separate session is started when I use token launched forgot password form to reset password. How can I codify
reseturl to use active session only?
public function sendToken($email, $resetUrl) {
    // Validate email address
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return false; // Invalid email address
    }

    // Output or log the value of the reset URL
    echo "Reset URL: $resetUrl"; // Output to screen
    
    // Encode HTML content
    $emailBody = '<br><br>To reset your password, click <a href="' . $resetUrl . '" target="_self">here</a>.';

    // Set additional headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Your Name <your_email@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: Your Name <your_email@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    // Send email
    $subject = 'Reset your password';
    if (mail($email, $subject, $emailBody, $headers)) {

       return true; // Email sent successfully
    }

    return false; // Failed to send email
            
} 

I tried above code but url form uses a seperate session and I cannot update my user database. I have user Authentication using Session for security.

I don't see any reference to $_SESSION in the code. What do sessions have to do with it?

$resetUrl = $basePath . "http/controllers/session/reset-password.php?token=" . urlencode($plainToken);    My question is should I include $_SESSION in my token so that form launches in Active session? How can I do this in your experience?

$_SESSION is an array, it holds all the session variables the script has set. You don't put it in tokens, the script just uses session_start() to resume the current session and then accesses $_SESSION['variable_name'].

But there's no reason to expect that the user's session will still be active when they respond to the password reset email.

Whether the session is the same or not depends on the browser which is used to open the link from the email. The server cannot control that. I suggest that you make it simply so that the token in the email can be linked to the correct user (e.g. because it's stored against that user in the database). Often a password reset will happen when the user is not logged in anyway (e.g. because they forgot their password), so requiring an authenticated session for this seems a bit counterproductive anyway

Thanks for the tip. You are absolutely right. Authenticated session is indeed not logical. I was on the wrong track. Need to work on browser

I just saw another question with similar issue. $_POST['$token] is required for submitting form data. I only used $token in $_GET. Thank you for your help.!!!
